# Clear from CALayer mask?

Tags: ios, calayer, mask, alpha, composition

I have a base layer, masked with a transparent mask layer.

Mask layer have a sublayer, a transparent circle.
Works fine, the base layer is masked with the circle.

**But I want to clear (zero out) the mask pixels with the circle.** Not fill up with.
Can you get what I want?

How?

---

[image]

You can see the alpha channels of the mask images here.

---

It is a 60 fps animation, so allocating instances/custom drawing every frame I think is not a solution, that would cut down performance.

Comment: Too complex question wording... (?)

Answer (score 0):

It can be carried out **via custom drawing only**, in a CALAyer subclass (at least on iOS, having no any CIFilter for blending yet). Exactly what I wanted to avoid. :(

There are many ways, but the simplest seems to use the clear blend mode.

```
// Draw with Clear (!) blend mode.
CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeClear);
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, self.color.CGColor);
CGContextFillPath(context);
```

Don't even need any clipping or masking. Maybe I'll gain performance by cache the path renderings.